# Is it advisable to render the GET part of the page when a CSRF FAILURE occurs?

Tags: django, csrf, django-csrf, csrf-protection

I have setup a website in django and added csrf middleware. I could see CSRF failures frequently from the website. Currently I display a 500 error page when CSRF failure occurs.

However, I am thinking of loading the same URL as a GET request whenever a CSRF failure occurs, and ask the user to resubmit the form again. Is this method advisable? What will be the security issues that will arise due to this? Any thoughts on this will be helpful.

Comment: CSRF Failure means something was not done correctly, in that case I see no reason to remove the 500 error (which informs about an error).

Comment: Does my post help answer your question? Please let me know if you require further info.

Answer (score 0):

As any attacker will not have access to the response due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), you may return whatever you like including a `200 OK` with a description to help the user.

If you wanted you could include a `500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR` response, but you could also include some HTML content to advise the user that they should resubmit the form.